# Is there a way to get "All" note books via API?

Tags: evernote

I'm considering implementing Evernote Teams, but in order to build a business flow, I need to obtain a "list of notebooks that can be viewed by logged-in users" via API.

Therefore, we initially built it with the assumption that NoteStore.listNotebooks would be used.
https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listNotebooks

However, in this case, it seems that notebooks created from spaces are not included in the list, so I am having trouble meeting the requirements this time...
(Notebooks created directly, not under a space, can be retrieved)

How can I get a notebook similar to what I'm viewing in the GUI via the API? ?

I tried calling NoteStore.listAccessibleBusinessNotebooks, but I couldn't get it either.
https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listAccessibleBusinessNotebooks
However, when I "published" the notebook to a directory, I was able to retrieve it.
However, for this requirement, it would be difficult to "publish" the notebook to a directory due to permission management.